# Is cosmological expansion paradoxical?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, causality

Suppose that there are three points in space. The distance between any two of the closest points is less than or equal to the cosmological horizon. Such is the case that information cannot be transmitted between points outside of the cosmological horizon (e.g., between the blue and green polka dots). However, if there is a middle point in space within this boundary (say the red polka dot), from this point, the furthest point (green polka dot) can be reached. In other words, from blue to green the distance is too far, but from blue to red and then to green the distance is reachable. I find this paradoxical but most likely I am wrong or missing something. Can someone explain how my logic is wrong?

P.S. I have no physics background but have taken basic physics and math courses so I can understand anything until calculus 3.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/753858/180843

Comment: keep in mind that the horizon can also change with time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the three dots are blue, red and green, where red is within the cosmological horizon of both blue and green, but blue and green are not within each other's horizons.

In that case, in the time it takes for a signal to go from blue to red, the green dot moves outside the horizon of the red dot. Concretely (numbers greatly exaggerated), suppose it takes $1000$ years for a signal to go between blue and red, and another $1000$ years for a signal to go from red to green. Then although green is within red's cosmological horizon *now*, it is not within red's cosmological horizon $1000$ years from now. Blue cannot therefore send a signal to green by first sending it to red.